# Kubuntu 18.10 touchpad cannot be configured

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, multi-touch

Most of the touchpad settings are grayed out, so I can't alter things like touchpad sensitivity our multi-finger clicks. I ran Official Ubuntu (GNOME) 18.10 a few days ago on the same laptop without these issues.

My touchpad dos not appear to be synaptics, so I don't think the other questions apply

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA7813:00 06CB:1788                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA2B31:00 06CB:7F8C Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Comment: Seems related to [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=387153) with no resolution in the short term.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this by installing a different touchpad driver.  I believe I used `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` apt package which does work as well as the GNOME driver but at least enables configuring through the standard Kubuntu GUI.